# WP_User_Query order by meta_key that is an array

Tags: php, array, wp-user-query

I have set a user metadata named `achievements` which is an array containing various numeric values. Using `WP_User_Query`, I want to order the list by a specific key within this array named `points`.

The following:

```
$args = array(
    'order' => 'DESC',
    'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
    'meta_key' => 'achievements',
    'number' => $no,
    'offset' => $offset
);
```

...works if `achievements` would be a numeric value. How do I alter the `$args` array to target the key `points` within the metadata key `achievements`.

Running a `print_r()` of `achievements` for a user returns:

```
Array ( [x1] => 74 [x2] => 383 [x3] => 457 [x4] => 81 [points] => 301 [x5] => 382 [x6] => 12 )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could save the values with the **separate** user meta keys:

```
x1, ..., x6, points
```

instead of the array:

```
achievements
```

to simplify your `WP_User_Query()` usage and not having to deal with *serialized arrays* as user meta values.

*But I guess you've already considered this setup and wanted to avoid it ;-)*

A compromise would be to move only the `points` out of the `achievements` array into a separate meta key.

**Update:**

When the number of users is relatively small, we can use the following (untested) PHP sorting:

```
$users2points = array();

$args = array(
    'meta_key' => 'achievements',
    'number'   => $no,
    'offset'   => $offset
);

$users = get_users( $args );

foreach( (array) $users as $user )
{
    $meta = get_user_meta( 'achievements', $user->ID );
    if( isset( $meta['points'] )
        $users2points[$user->ID] = $meta['points'];
}

asort( $users2points, SORT_NUMERIC );

print_r( $users2points );
```

**Update 2:**

Here's another more adventures PHP sorting that will work directly on the `$users` array of `WP_User` objects:

```
$args = array(
    'meta_key' => 'achievements',
    'number'   => $no,
    'offset'   => $offset
);

$users = get_users( $args );

foreach( (array) $users as $user )
{
    $meta = get_user_meta( 'achievements', $user->ID );

    // Here we assume the points values are greater or equal to 0:
    $user->points = ( isset( $meta['points'] ) ?  $meta['points'] : 0;
}

/*
usort( $users, function( $a, $b ) {
    return gmp_cmp( $a->points, $b->points );
});
*/

// The gmp_cmp() might suffer from a memory leak,
// according to some PHP bug reports,
// so let's use this instead:    

usort( $users, function( $a, $b ) {
    if( $a->points === $b->points )
        return 0;
    else
        return ( $a->points > $b->points ) ? 1 : -1;
});


print_r( $users );
```

Comment: Yes, I have considered to move 'points' out of 'achievements', but instead of adding another user metadata only for this query, I am hoping to avoid it. Is there any way to deal with this serialized array in my query?

Comment: I think you will have to use some SQL magic or move the ordering to PHP.

Comment: Thus I am hoping for a magician. =D

Comment: I updated the answer with some PHP sorting, but no magic there I'm afraid ;-)

Comment: Thank you very much for the updated examples. I do have one important question though. Is it worth while to go this route or should I simply just separate the 'points' into its own user metadata? Would that save on performance? The reason why I didn't want to do this in the first place is because I thought it would be unnecessary to add another metadata just for one query when the value exists in an array. What's your professional input?

Comment: I guess it's very opinionated ;-) The meta arrays can be convenient but they are problematic for sorting/ordering. It's hard to generalize but I'm afraid we have to add the extra complexity somewhere in order solve this (i.e. as extra meta get/update routines or som extra PHP sorting code or extra SQL). I think I would first try to add it as an extra meta. But if I need more flexible solution, where the orderby fields are likely to change in the future, I would use the PHP solution or try some SQL magic that I haven't investigated here. Sorry no black & white answer, just  gray dust here ;-)

Comment: PS: it also depends on the number of users, I think the PHP method is not suitable for huge number of users, because we would need to fetch them all to sort them.

Comment: Thank you for the details. It is for a large amount of users. Therefore, I have gone with adding the key within its own metadata. I will mark this as correct as I am sure many others in the same situation will find this useful. Strange how there isn't much information about this on the web.

Answer (score 1):

A way to do it using SQL is to use `SUBSTR` and `LOCATE` to pick out the serialized value:

```
function wpse162668_pre_user_query( $query ) {
    if ( ( $orderby = $query->get( 'orderby' ) ) != 'achievements_points' ) {
        return $query;
    }
    global $wpdb;

    $order = $query->get( 'order' );
    $points_str = 's:6:"points";i:';
    $query->query_fields .= $wpdb->prepare(
        ', SUBSTR(wp_usermeta.meta_value, LOCATE(%s, wp_usermeta.meta_value) + %d)+0 AS ' . $orderby,
        $points_str, strlen( $points_str )
    );
    $query->query_orderby = 'ORDER BY ' . $orderby . ' ' . $order . ', user_login ASC';

    return $query;
}
```

and then change the `$args` `orderby` to `'orderby' => 'achievements_points'` and wrap the `get_users` with the filter:

```
add_filter( 'pre_user_query', 'wpse162668_pre_user_query', 10, 2 );
$users = get_users( $args );
remove_filter( 'pre_user_query', 'wpse162668_pre_user_query', 10 );
```

The cast to integer (`+0`) works cos MySQL just ignores trailing non-numeric stuff. I use this method quite a lot (on postmeta, not usermeta) in varying combinations, due to using the WPAlchemy_MetaBox class with repeat groups, though it can get very messy.